# How to make eclipse validate jsp files automatically

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I have search for an Option in eclipes to let him validate the contents of JSP files automatically when the workspace ist compiled.

I didn't find any usefull results.

Do you have an idea how to do that?

Comment: Are you trying to compile them into class files to deploy, or just validate their contents?

Comment: I just want to validate their contents.

Comment: Do you have the Java EE IDE installed? Are the JSPs in a Dynamic Web Project is at least a Java project with the proper API jars on the Java Build Path?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this **via a project builder Ant build file**.

See Eclipse help: [Creating a project builder Ant buildfile](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-93_project_builder.htm)

The [`org.eclipse.help.webapp`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/gerrit/platform/eclipse.platform.ua.git/tree/org.eclipse.help.webapp) project does the same:

- The [Ant build file](https://git.eclipse.org/c/gerrit/platform/eclipse.platform.ua.git/tree/org.eclipse.help.webapp/buildJSPs.xml) to compile the JSP files
- The Ant file [added as project builder](https://git.eclipse.org/c/gerrit/platform/eclipse.platform.ua.git/tree/org.eclipse.help.webapp/.project#n23) (to automatically run the Ant script when the workspace ist compiled)